# clojure - :refer vs :as

Tags: performance, clojure

I'm learning clojure.
As part of the `:require` process, there is an option to use `:refer` for a specific method or all the methods.

Or to use the `:as` and then to choose the method you need.

I think I understand the difference between the 2 options, and also seen the documentation [here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require) that says:

> :as takes a symbol as its argument and makes that symbol an alias to the
>     lib's namespace in the current namespace.
>
> :refer takes a list of symbols to refer from the namespace or the :all
>   keyword to bring in all public vars.

But I'm still not sure about:

1. When should I use one option and not the other?
2. Is there a **performance difference** between the two options? (My thoughts say that there is non since the compilar will optimize both options

(I also did 2 small programs that uses `core.asyc`, one uses `:as` and one uses `:refer`. The time it took to run both was pretty much the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I pretty much always use `:as` like this:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str] ))

(println (str/join ["hello" "there"]))
```

This allows the reader to see that `join` belongs to `str` (a namespace alias), and they can easily see that `join` resolves to `clojure.string/join`.

Consider the alternate:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:require
    [clojure.string :refer [join] ))

<snip>
...397 lines of other code...
</snip>

(println (join ["hello" "there"]))
```

Here `join` looks like a local function defined in `demo.core`, and it can take a while for the reader to figure out where it comes from.  They can still trace down the origin by looking in the `ns` declaration, but unless it is a very common function, most people agree that the namespace alias technique is easier/faster to grok when reading code you didn't write.

---

In execution, the compiler will convert both forms to the same machine code, so there is no difference there.

Comment: At best something like slamhound may help with the automatic refering, but it usually is to much hastle for me.  I second to use _consistent_ aliases over your project namespaces for requiring. This makes refactoring easier too with blunt tools..

Comment: See also [Stuart’s Opinionated Style Guide for Clojure Namespace Declarations](https://stuartsierra.com/2016/clojure-how-to-ns.html): _"Do not ':use'. Do not ':refer :all'. Do not ':rename'. Use ':require :refer' only for very frequently-used symbols._